# Portable shell code to print alternative text

Tags: shell-script, shell

Playing on a question for [codegolf.se](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50270/codegolf-heads-or-tails) I am out of ideas. Is there some other approach (reasonably short, of course) that I haven't tried?

Given `i` contains either `heads` or `tails`, correspondingly output `1` or `-1`.

Alternatives tried:

- ```
  <<<$[#i%7-5]                    # 12 bytes but only zsh.
  ```

  [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@WX6SQqZCZp5CRmphSrFCSmJlTbK2Qkv/fxsZGJVo5U9Vc1zT2f0p@Xup/AA)
- ```
  <<<$[30#$i%7-1]                 # 15 bytes but only zsh.
  ```

  [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@WX6SQqZCZp5CRmphSrFCSmJlTbK2Qkv/fxsZGJdrYQFklU9Vc1zD2f0p@Xup/AA)
- ```
  echo $[30#$i%7-1]               # 17 bytes but only in bash, zsh.
  ```

  [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@WX6SQqZCZp5CRmphSrFCSmJlTbK2Qkv8/NTkjX0El2thAWSVT1VzXMPZ/Sn5e6n8A)
- ```
  echo $((30#$i%7-1))             # 19 bytes but only bash,ksh,zsh.
  ```

  [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@kkKmQmaeQkZqYUqxQkpiZU2ytkJL/PzU5I19BRUPD2EBZJVPVXNdQU/N/Sn5e6n8A)
- ```
  he=2;echo $[${i%a*}-1]          # 22 bytes But only in bash,zsh.
  ```

  [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@kkKmQmaeQkZqYUqxQkpiZU2ytkJL/PyPV1sg6NTkjX0ElWqU6UzVRq1bXMPZ/Sn5e6n8A)
- ```
  a=${i%h*};echo ${a:+-}1         # 23 bytes. best portable code
  ```

  [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvifll@kkKmQmaeQkZqYUqxQkpiZU2ytkJL/P9FWpTpTNUOr1jo1OSNfQaU60Upbt9bwf0p@Xup/AA)
- ```
  he=2;echo $((${i%a*}-1))        # 24 bytes, portable.
  ```

  [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@kkKmQmaeQkZqYUqxQkpiZU2ytkJL/PyPV1sg6NTkjX0FFQ0OlOlM1UatW11BT839Kfl7qfwA)
- ```
  (IFS=h;set $i;echo ${1:+-}1)    # 28 (subshell) or 26 (changing IFS).
  ```

  [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvifll@kkKmQmaeQkZqYUqxQkpiZU2ytkJL/X8PTLdg2w7o4tURBJdM6NTkjX0Gl2tBKW7fWUPN/Sn5e6n8A)
- ```
  (IFS=h;set $i;echo $(($#*2-3))) # 31 bytes, portable.
  ```

  [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S0kszvifll@kkKmQmaeQkZqYUqxQkpiZU2ytkJL/X8PTLdg2w7o4tURBJdM6NTkjX0FFQ0NFWctI11hTU/N/Sn5e6n8A)

Note: Using `dash` as a reasonable simile of a portable shell tester.

Comment: There's `expr $i : he - 1`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good one! Thanks.